# Add extra fields to django form depending on another field value

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a model 'Project' that is supposed to take multiple installment percentages of the total project cost. For example, if total cost of the project is $100, there can be four or five or as many installments are set. So one field is `'num_installment' = 4` (say). Now each installment can have different percentages of total cost (eg, 50,30,10,10 or any such combination). The problem is, since we don't know the number of installments prior to the form validation, the installment percentage fields can't be set before hand. So we need a dynamic form where four (or `n` number of) installment fields are popped up according to the `num_installment` field value.

The Project model-

```py
class Project(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    net_charge = models.FloatField(null=True)
    num_installment = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    installments = ??????
```

ProjectForm:

```py
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        try:
            self.client = kwargs.pop('client')
            super(ProjectForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
            self.fields['client'].queryset = Client.objects.filter(id=self.client.id)
        except:
            super(ProjectForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```py
def createProject(request,pk):
    client = Client.objects.get(id=int(pk))
    form = ProjectForm(client=client)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ProjectForm(request.POST,client=client)

            if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('projects')

    context ={
        'form':form,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'accounts/project_form.html',context)
```

Comment: Hi Nazish, welcome! Would you be able to included the View for the form (the class or function in your views.py file that contains the form). I have an idea I want to try and the view would be helpful if you don't mind?